# angular2 routing with angular router 3 rc-1

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-cli

I m following this tutorial http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/14/routing-in-angular-2-revisited.html#demos to implement a router in my new angular2 app

**here is my routing code :**

```
      import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
      import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
      import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

      import { LogComponent } from './app/log/log.component.ts';
      import { ReplayComponent } from './app/replay/replay.component.ts';

      import { AppRoutes } from './app.routes';

      @NgModule({

        imports: 
        [
          BrowserModule,
          RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)
        ],

        declarations: 
        [
          LogComponent,
          ReplayComponent
        ],

        bootstrap: [LogComponent]
      })
```

For some reason it fails to compile with this error

Error: Typescript found the following errors:  folder/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-Q0BBqeqo.tmp/0/src/main.ts (25, 3): Declaration expected.

line 25 is the latest line of the router code, looks like the compiler dont like the ")" at the end.

LogComponent & Replaycomponent are just defaults scripts generated via ng g component  (angular cli) and have not been edited yet.

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { LogComponent } from './app/log/log.component';
import { ReplayComponent } from './app/replay/replay.component';

export const AppRoutes = [
 { path: '', component: LogComponent },
 { path : '/replay', component : ReplayComponent}
];
```

Comment: looks like the compiler is looking for an exported class like this export class mainComponent  {}, if I add it , it compiles fine but the I get an error @ app launch

Comment: I also tried to duplicate the plunker exemple from here with no luck https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-5/ts/plnkr.html , copied all the files from the plunk zip file and my src folder and get a 404 error : Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/app/main.ts(…) - dont know if it s a good idea to use angular2 @ this time , maybe it s too early.